# Editing a MahApps Metro Circle Toggle button

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-interface, mahapps.metro

I know there are a few questions surrounding the MahApps Metro styles, but i haven't found one that address the issue I am having. 
I have an app that I am maintaining, a lot of which I helped build, using a central style XAML repository. 
A part that I didn't build uses the style for the Metro Circle Toggle Button from MahApps. According to my Stakeholders, I need to change the selected state to be more contrasting from the normal state of the button. However I haven't been able to find where to go to access that style in my application.

My gut instinct is to create a complete style in my repository that replaces the Metro Style, but I figured I would ask around to see if anyone here could help me.

Any Hints wold be greatly appreciated.

**Update 1:**
I tried to use the BasedOn property to keep the amount of code down. I then set the background color to switch from black to white when "IsChecked" is True.
here is the code i added:

```
   <Style x:Key="CustomCircleToggleButtonStyle"
       TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource  MetroCircleToggleButtonStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DarkBorder}"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True" >
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
```

Unfortunately, there is some animation form the MahApps sinking through that makes the button go from the black, immediately to white then fade to the dark blue color that i am trying to get rid of.

Here is the wpf toggle button:

```
   <ToggleButton Width="50" IsEnabled="{Binding IsMultipleSelected,Converter=    {StaticResource BooleanNegate}}"
                          Height="50"
                          Style="{DynamicResource CustomCircleToggleButtonStyle}" 
                          Command="{Binding Path=GroupSelectCommand}" 
                          IsChecked="{Binding IsLasoSelected}">

            <Rectangle Width="20"
                           Height="20"
                           Fill="{DynamicResource IconButtonActiveBorder}">
                <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                    <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill"
                                 Visual="{DynamicResource appbar_lasso}" />
                </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
            </Rectangle>
        </ToggleButton>
```

I am hoping to move a lot of this into the style, but I have to keep functional.

Comment: This is actually pretty simple. Can you show the style template (name taken from their docs) "MetroCircleToggleButtonStyle"?

Comment: Hey Chris... Thanks for taking a look at this for me.. i updated to include Code samples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To close the loop, and post my answer for everyone else with the issue, I ended up creating a style that i put in my style repository. I think my Solution might be a little unique though as i don't actually have access the the MahApps.Metro source code in my solution.

Here is what I did:

```
   <Style x:Key="CircleButton" TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource MyFocusVisual}"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2 2 2 2"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="45"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="45"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                <Grid>
                    <Ellipse x:Name="BorderCircle">
                        <Ellipse.Fill>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="SlateGray"/>
                        </Ellipse.Fill>
                    </Ellipse>
                    <Ellipse  x:Name="BodyCircle" Margin="3" >
                        <Ellipse.Fill >
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="Black"/>
                        </Ellipse.Fill>
                    </Ellipse>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="Mask"
                        Width="20"
                           Height="20"
                           Fill="{DynamicResource IconButtonActiveBorder}">
                        <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                            <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill"
                                 Visual="{DynamicResource appbar_lasso}" />
                        </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                    </Rectangle>
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="content" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="BodyCircle" Property="Fill" Value="White"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="BorderCircle" Property="Fill" Value="Black"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Mask" Property="Fill" Value="Black"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="BodyCircle" Property="Fill" Value="DarkOrange"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="BorderCircle" Property="Fill" Value="Black"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Mask" Property="Fill" Value="Black"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

This gives me total control of all aspects of the toggle button and the identical look as it had before. All i have to do to implement it is call it from the WPF view:

```
    <ToggleButton  IsEnabled="{Binding IsMultipleSelected,Converter={StaticResource BooleanNegate}}"
                          Style="{DynamicResource CircleButton}" 
                          Command="{Binding Path=GroupSelectCommand}" 
                          IsChecked="{Binding IsLasoSelected}">
        </ToggleButton>
```

Hope this helps others out.

Answer (score 2):

Right, so the reason it's not working with your example is you can't overwrite triggers that interact with ControlTemplate via Triggers from the Style....

So, if we go take a peek at line 615 [here](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/master/MahApps.Metro/Styles/Controls.Buttons.xaml) (which btw, I assume there's a file in your metro stuff named the same) we see inside the template the `ControlTemplate.Triggers` which on IsChecked is changing the opacity of `ellipsebg` ellipse. It in turn is hard set to fill of `{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}`...

So...you could overwrite that brush at the instance level....or, just go edit the full style template to use a different brush all together.

In other words you could go change line 630 of `Fill="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}"` to another brush or brush resource and it would inherit to each instance (that would be my choice to keep centrally maintainable properties).

Or, at the instance something like:

```
<StackPanel>
  <StackPanel.Resources>
     <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AccentColorBrush">Red</SolidColorBrush>
     <Style TargetType="ToggleButton" 
            BasedOn="{DynamicResource CustomCircleToggleButtonStyle}"/>
  </StackPanel.Resources>

  <ToggleButton/>
  <ToggleButton/>
  <ToggleButton/>

</StackPanel>
```

Make sense? :)

Comment: I have a bunch of different references to the MahApps.Metro throughout the projects in my solution, but I dont have a Controls.Button.xaml anywhere.

Comment: @tCoe fair enough, I never used mahapps since I generally always made my own stuff but I would assume you could extract the style template via finding an instance right-clicking->Edit Template->Edit a copy(or original if it lets you have the option)

Comment: I decided to rewrite the entire button style in my repository. That way I can control all aspects of it like with the other things we have worked on together. Still bugs me where that blue was coming from, but it isnt showing up in my style.

Comment: @tCoe blue? You mean the brush set for `AccentColorBrush` that it's applying to the ellipse `Fill`?

Comment: it was almost part of the animation. with the code that i posted above, you would think that the final state of that button was white, but it faded to a Dark blue color.

Comment: maybe line 667 in your link?

Comment: @tCoe the foreground? The only storyboard in there I see is for the opacity of "ellipsebg"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130150/discussion-between-tcoe-and-chris-w).